# Bluetooth not working with Ralink RT3290 In Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and my Bluetooth (RT3290) was not working so I reinstalled its driver using GDEBI package installer. After I tried command `sudo modprobe rtbth` it started working but it does not do anything, no device is visible and also my laptop is not also visible to any device.

When I try `service bluetooth status` it displays me this

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-01-18 18:39:32 IST; 40s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 15857 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4514)
     Memory: 2.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─15857 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 18 18:39:32 Piyush-X55C systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan 18 18:39:32 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[15857]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Jan 18 18:39:32 Piyush-X55C systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 18 18:39:32 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[15857]: Starting SDP server
Jan 18 18:39:32 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[15857]: Bluetooth management interface 1.17 initialized
Jan 18 18:39:35 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[15857]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.68 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jan 18 18:39:35 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[15857]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.68 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```

Output of `rfkill list`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Now the bluetooth is started but not finding any device and also visible to any other device.

Output of `sudo btmgmt info`

```
Index list with 1 item
hci0:   Primary controller
    addr A4:17:31:1D:65:54 version 4 manufacturer 91 class 0x000000
    supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr debug-keys 
    current settings: bondable ssp br/edr 
    name Piyush-X55C
    short name
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118631/discussion-on-question-by-piyush-mhatre-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-20-04).